# difference between right click and "copy as LaTeX" and directly using TeXForm

Tags: piecewise, latex

```
Piecewise[{{True, a <= -2}, 
 {x <= (1/3)*(-4 + 4*a) || x >= 4 + 4*a, 
   Inequality[-2, Less, a, LessEqual, -1]}, 
 {x <= (1/3)*(-4 + 4*a) || x >= (1/3)*(4 + 4*a), 
   Inequality[-1, Less, a, LessEqual, 1]}, 
 {x <= -4 + 4*a || x >= (1/3)*(4 + 4*a), 
   1 < a < 2}, {True, a >= 2}}, 0]
```

if directly using `//TeXForm` ,it will give out

```
\begin{cases}
\text{True} & a\leq -2 \\
 x\leq \frac{1}{3} (4 a-4)\lor x\geq 4 a+4 & -2<a\leq
-1 \\
 x\leq \frac{1}{3} (4 a-4)\lor x\geq \frac{1}{3} (4
 a+4) & -1<a\leq 1 \\
 x\leq 4 a-4\lor x\geq \frac{1}{3} (4 a+4) & 1<a<2 \\
\text{True} & a\geq 2
 \end{cases}
```

$$\begin{cases}
\text{True} & a\leq -2 \\
 x\leq \frac{1}{3} (4 a-4)\lor x\geq 4 a+4 & -2<a\leq
-1 \\
 x\leq \frac{1}{3} (4 a-4)\lor x\geq \frac{1}{3} (4
 a+4) & -1<a\leq 1 \\
 x\leq 4 a-4\lor x\geq \frac{1}{3} (4 a+4) & 1<a<2 \\
\text{True} & a\geq 2
 \end{cases}$$

which is correct. But if I do this(select-> right clicking-> copy as-> LaTeX)

[image]

it will return

```
\begin{array}{cc}
\{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
\text{True} & a\leq -2 \\
x\leq \frac{1}{3} (4 a-4)\lor x\geq 4 a+4 & -2<a\leq -1 \\
x\leq \frac{1}{3} (4 a-4)\lor x\geq \frac{1}{3} (4 a+4) & -1<a\leq 1 \\
x\leq 4 a-4\lor x\geq \frac{1}{3} (4 a+4) & 1<a<2 \\
\text{True} & a\geq 2 \\
\end{array}
\\
\end{array}
```

$$\begin{array}{cc}
\{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
\text{True} & a\leq -2 \\
x\leq \frac{1}{3} (4 a-4)\lor x\geq 4 a+4 & -2<a\leq -1 \\
x\leq \frac{1}{3} (4 a-4)\lor x\geq \frac{1}{3} (4 a+4) & -1<a\leq 1 \\
x\leq 4 a-4\lor x\geq \frac{1}{3} (4 a+4) & 1<a<2 \\
\text{True} & a\geq 2 \\
\end{array}
\\
\end{array}$$

Which is not so good.

So what cause the difference?

Comment: Probably one uses the actual expression, the other uses the box form. I would let Wolfram know, even if it's not a bug.

Comment: Incidentally, I just ran into this too. Notice how the $\{$ is too small [here](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#igkirchhoffmatrix).